# Multi user login using c# and ms access database, error is rows position?

Tags: c#

Please help, on how to solve this one..

Here is my **Login** table's structure:

```
 Username, Password, Position
```

Actually the code is running, and it shows the messagebox "Login Success". The problem is the form

```
frmHome home = new frmHome(); 
home.Show();
```

and

```
frmAdminHome ah = new frmAdminHome(); 
ah.Show();
```

did not show and throws an error on

```
if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()=="admin")
```

hmmp.. there's no row on position? seems its the errors says.

I need help on how to fix this one.. I need your guidance guys..

This code is on button click event, I am using C# and MS Access database:

```
try
{
    string user, pass;
    user = Convert.ToString(txtUsername.Text);
    pass = Convert.ToString(txtPassword.Text);

    con.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username = '" +user+ "' AND Password = '" + pass + "' ";

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    int count = 0;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }

    if (count == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Success!");
        this.Hide();

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()=="admin")
        {
            frmHome home = new frmHome();
            home.Show();

            Visible = false;
        }
        else if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "staff")
        {
            frmAdminHome ah = new frmAdminHome();
            ah.Show();

            Visible = false;
        }
    }
    else if (count > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is not correct!");
    }

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex);
}
```

Comment: `dt = new DataTable();`....`dt.Rows[0][0]`, you didn't load anything onto the DataTable

Comment: so what it means? please tell..

Comment: It means you can't use the data before you actually load the data.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you should not have duplicate rows having same username and password.

this should be prevented when user is created in the system. You should not allow duplicate usernames. If you handle that you won't need to check for duplicates at the time of login.

For now you can use following approach to solve your current issue.

You are getting data returned from the query into the DataReader and you read it using `reader.Read()` but you never populate the datatable using `OleDbDataAdapter da`

```
try
    {
        string user, pass;
        user = txtUsername.Text; // You don't need Convert.ToString as TextBox.Text is already string. 
        pass = txtPassword.Text;

        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        var query = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username = '" +user+ "' AND Password = '" + pass + "' ";

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);             
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds); //Populate data set via adapter.

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]; //Get the first table from the dataset
        int count = dt.Rows.Count;

        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Success!");
            this.Hide();
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()=="admin")
            {
                frmHome home = new frmHome();
                home.Show();
                Visible = false;
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "staff")
            {
                frmAdminHome ah = new frmAdminHome();
                ah.Show();
                Visible = false;
            }
        }

        else if (count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password!");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is not correct!");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex);
    }
```

This should help you resolve your issue.